# How to append the child to the parent without using the ID element?

Tags: javascript, html

I used an ID to add a new element to divTwo. I want to know how to add the p tag inside divOne and divTwo without referring to their identifier. please help.

```js
 // create Tag 
    const createElement = (elementName) => document.createElement(elementName);
    const appendTo = (idElement, element) => document.getElementById(idElement).append(element);
    const setAttribute = (eleName, attribute, valueAttribute) => eleName.setAttribute(attribute, valueAttribute);
    const setText = (id, text) => document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;

    // Tag HTML

    // div one
    const divOne = createElement("div");
    const appendDivOne = appendTo("demo", divOne)
    const setIDOne = setAttribute(divOne, "id", "divOne");
    // div two 
    const divTwo = createElement("div");
    const appendDivTwo = appendTo("demo", divTwo)
    const setIDTwo = setAttribute(divTwo, "id", "divTwo");
    // child div two
    const divTwoChild = createElement("p");
    const appendDivTwoChild = appendTo("divTwo", divTwoChild);
    const setIDChildeTwo = setAttribute(divTwoChild, "id", "ChildeTwo");
    const text = setText("ChildeTwo", "childe two");
```

```html
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to append to div1 which, according to your code, will be the first element in . If you want to append a P tag, you can do:

```
const divOneChild = createElement("p")
const appendP = appendTo(document.getElementById("demo").firstChild, divOneChild)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your elements directly after creation... for example when using `const divTwoChild = createElement("p");`, you can use `divTwoChild.append()` ... there is also a function called `insertAdjacentHTML()`, where you can add a html code directly on given position, read about in in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacenthtml.asp). Examples below (last 3 lines):

```js
 // create Tag 
    const createElement = (elementName) => document.createElement(elementName);
    const appendTo = (idElement, element) => document.getElementById(idElement).append(element);
    const setAttribute = (eleName, attribute, valueAttribute) => eleName.setAttribute(attribute, valueAttribute);
    const setText = (id, text) => document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;

    // Tag HTML

    // div one
    const divOne = createElement("div");
    const appendDivOne = appendTo("demo", divOne)
    const setIDOne = setAttribute(divOne, "id", "divOne");
    // div two 
    const divTwo = createElement("div");
    const appendDivTwo = appendTo("demo", divTwo)
    const setIDTwo = setAttribute(divTwo, "id", "divTwo");
    // child div two
    const divTwoChild = createElement("p");
    const appendDivTwoChild = appendTo("divTwo", divTwoChild);
    const setIDChildeTwo = setAttribute(divTwoChild, "id", "ChildeTwo");

    divTwoChild.append("childe two"); // <-- here
    divOne.append('I am div one!'); // <-- or here
    divTwo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>I am a new p in div 2!</p>'); // <-- or here
```

```html
    <div id="demo"></div>
```